# Implementing hard reload in React

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, symfony, routes

I have a React app running on an apache/PHP server.

The React app loads on the home path. That is, PHP is configured to load `index.html` at the `/` route which loads the React app.

**index.html**

```
// ....
<div id="react-hook"></div>

<script>
    const wrapper = document.getElementById("react-hook");
    wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, wrapper) : false;
</script>
```

(Im actually using webpack but thats the jist of it)

Im using `react-router` to define some routes:

```
const Routes = () => (

    <div>                
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
    </div>

)
```

And rendering them with some links..

```
<Link to="/>Home</Link>     
<Link to="/login>Login</Link>
<Link to="/test>Test</Link>
```

**This works fine but when I hard reloaded the page, the route loaded was the one defined on the *server*.**

To address this, I set up a rule on the server to forward all requests to the home route `/` where `index.html` is located - that way my react app is loaded for all requests.

This is closer to solving my issue but now all hard-loaded routes land me at the home react route as opposed to the route I was attempting to reload.

```
behavior: /test (hard route) ---> / (soft route)

should be: /test (hard route) ---> /test (soft route)
```

What is the correct way to implement hard-reload for a react app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what server you are using. You do not want to forward all requests to `/`. You want to display `/index.html` *no matter what request you receive*. If the user requests `/test`, your server gives them `/index.html` but *calls it* `/test`. They do not get a 404, they do not get a 301. They get a status code 200 for `/test` but they get the contents of `/index.html`.

For nginx, this is something like `try_files $uri index.html`.

For Apache, you can use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite all *non-existent* (something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` for a condition that the file not exist for the rewrite to take place) paths to `/index.html` with `RewriteRule .* /index.html`.

The React app only needs the same entry point (`<App />`), and the React router on page load will use the page URL to navigate accordingly, so all routes use the same `index.html` to land where they are going.

Comment: ok I gochya! yes, bit incorrect thinking on my part. I am using Apache so I can do this in `.htaccess` - the one catch is that I do not actually want to serve `index.html` for *all* requests because I want to use that server as an API for react as well - so some routes will be API endpoints. but I can write these into the redirect rule (`/api/*` get served via php)